# Java8 .getMethod() vs ::getMethod

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am new in Java8 ,and I created this piece of code that is working fine

```
 userService.getClient().findUsersByMarkets(marketIds)
                .stream()
                .filter(us -> !alreadyNotifiedUserIds.contains(us.getId()))
                .forEach(usersToBeNotified::add);
```

but under my understandings this piece of code should also work fine, but is not the case and I am wondering why

```
     userService.getClient().findUsersByMarkets(marketIds)
        .stream()
        .filter(us -> !alreadyNotifiedUserIds.contains(User::getId))
        .forEach(usersToBeNotified::add);
```

Comment: You're switching between calling the method on an instance vs a class.

Comment: What understandings? `us.getId()` and `User::getId` are entirely different constructs.

Comment: As a side note, `.forEach(usersToBeNotified::add)` would be better implemented by `.collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: You would be right if you'd be using `filter(us -> us.isFoo())` which is equivalent to `filter(User::isFoo)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`User::getId` is a reference to a function so it's not equivalent to `contains(us.getId())`.

see --> https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx to familiarise your self with method references.

Comment: `User::getId` is shorthand equivalent for `(User x) -> x.getId()`